# Html Form POST values extracted fine when at localhost:8080 but empty string when deployed at AppSpot Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-go

Fri 2016.12.09

This simple POST handler will extract form values when running at localhost:8080. [[1](https://siongui.github.io/2016/03/27/go-server-get-form-post-value/)]

However, when deployed to AppSpot, the values are an empty string. Changing the form action to 'GET' works both at localhost:8080 and when deployed at AppSpot.

Tried r.PostFormValue("myValue")  and  r.FormValue("myValue") but both return ""
r.Method returns "POST"

Even tried adding: enctype="multipart/form-data" to form element

Thank you for looking into this,  Robin

[Golang source](https://siongui.github.io/2016/03/27/go-server-get-form-post-value/)

Sat 2016.12.10

cont: From GAEfan above

Try:
r.ParseForm()
myVal = r.Form["myValue"]

Although the current form Html does validate ttps://validator.w3.org/ I did take the time to be more formal and added the 'type' attribute as suggested.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Get Form POST Value</title></head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="/post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="myValue" value="qwert">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="my@email.com">
    <input type="text" name="data" value="somedata">
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue seems to be in the response. r.Body is always Nil when deployed at AppSpot.  Even with a    " defer r.Body.Close() "  preceding form value extraction, AppSpot always returns "http: invalid Read on closed Body" Since form values are part of the body response, this would explain why the values are always ""

ref: ttp://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
"Note that the query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request:"

```
func postHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  defer r.Body.Close()

  fmt.Fprintf(w, "<br>r.FormValue(\"myValue\")  [%s]", r.FormValue("myValue"))

  // and the suggestion from earlier

  r.ParseForm()
  myVal := r.Form["myValue"]
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "<br>myVal [%s]", myVal)

  bod, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(w, "<br>ERROR: ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body):  [%s]", err)
```

Even tried: ttps://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/getting-started/handling-user-input-in-forms but way too complex for their one line of form handling Content: r.FormValue("content")

Thank you for your keen observation on attributes. AppEngine at AppSpot apparently handles matters differently than at localhost, and I have yet to find a suitable tutorial.

Comment: More code needed.  Both for form and its handler.  Is `r` `request`?  If so, you need `r.POST.`...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
r.ParseForm()

myVal = r.Form["myValue"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. A quick cut-n-paste showed the same output. Works at localhost:8080 but fails when deployed to AppSpot.

Comment: Perhaps the improper form input is causing an issue.  Try: `<input type="text" name="myValue">`

Comment: Thank you for your keen observation on element attributes even though the Html content did validate. I'll continue in the edit block as this response section limited the number of chars to 600

Answer (score 0):

Sat 2016.12.10

Discovered this anomaly after hours of hair pulling:

To confirm the form was sending content, I had detected the Content-Length using

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "<br>Request Content-Length [%v]", r.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
```

before and after the defer r.Body.Close() statement, and saw the value change with the size of the form data I typed in. This value differed from the body length of zero so I knew the form was sending data. What this also did was
close the r.Body stream. Removing that line of code allowed the body contents to be decoded.

A word of caution to the wise . . .